# Running wordcount failed in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to run wordcount program in scala. Here's how my code looks like.

```
package myspark;

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.implicits._

object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
   val sc = new SparkContext( "local", "Word Count", "/home/hadoop/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin", Nil, Map(), Map())           
      val input = sc.textFile("/myspark/input.txt")             
      Val count = input.flatMap(line ⇒ line.split(" "))
      .map(word ⇒ (word, 1))
      .reduceByKey(_ + _)       
      count.saveAsTextFile("outfile")
      System.out.println("OK");
  }
}
```

Then I tried to execute it in spark.

```
spark-shell -i /myspark/WordCount.scala
```

And I get this error.

```
  ... 149 more
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
That file does not exist
```

Can someone please explain the error in this code? I am very new to Spark and Scala both. I have verified that the input.txt file is in the mentioned location.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look here to get started : [Learning Spark-WordCount](https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/mini-complete-example/src/main/scala/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/mini/scala/WordCount.scala)

Other than that there are many a errors that I can see

import org.apache.spark..implicits._: the two dots wont work

Other than that have you added spark-dependency in your project ? Maybe even as provided ?  You must do that atleast to run the spark code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether you have added the right `dependencies` . An i can see you did few mistake in your code .

create `Sparksession` not `Sparkcontext` [SparkSessionAPI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("Spark SQL basic example")
.config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
.getOrCreate()
```

Then use this `spark` variable

```
import spark.implicits._
```

I am not sure why you have mentioned `import org.apache.spark..implicits._` 2 `dot` between the `spark..implicits`